# How to connect to Kafka through JMS on OpenLiberty?

Tags: apache-kafka, jms, payara, jms-topic, open-liberty

Im trying to connect to Kafka with JMS. I followed [this guide](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/apache-kafka/getting-started-with-apache-kafka-and-wildfly) to use the Payara Kafka Connector. This worked on Wildfly. But I cant get it to work on OpenLiberty.

The `server.xml`:

```xml
<resourceAdapter id="kafkajmsra" location="${shared.resource.dir}kafka-rar-0.5.0.rar"/>

<jmsTopicConnectionFactory jndiName="JMSTopicFactory">
     <properties.kafkajmsra
                bootstrapServerConfig="kafka:9092"/>
</jmsTopicConnectionFactory>

<jmsTopic id="kafkaTopic" jndiName="JmsTopic">
     <properties.kafkajmsra topicName="demoTopic" />
</jmsTopic>
```

With those configurations I get a NullPointerException if I try to inject those components. The JNDI names can be found but not with these parameters.

```java
@Resource(lookup = "JMSTopicFactory")
private TopicConnectionFactory jmsTopicFactory;

@Resource(lookup = "JMSTopic")
private Topic jmsTopic;
```

Am I missing something in the `server.xml`?

---

I tried using the default JMS Connector. It does connect to Kafka, but the connection gets refused and on the kafka side it tells me this:

```
[2020-05-31 20:05:27,134] WARN [SocketServer brokerId=1] Unexpected error from /172.20.0.4; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = -1091633152)
 at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:103)
 at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:448)
 at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:398)
 at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:678)
 at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:580)
 at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:485)
 at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:893)
 at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:792)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

---

EDIT:

I changed the `server.xml` to look like this now:

```xml
    <resourceAdapter id="kafkajmsra" location="${shared.resource.dir}/kafka-rar-0.4.0.rar"/>

    <connectionFactory jndi="java:app/KafkaConnectionFactory"
                       interfaceName="fish.payara.cloud.connectors.kafka.api.KafkaConnectionFactory"
                       resourceAdapter="liberty/wlp/usr/shared/resources/kafka-rar-0.4.0.rar">
    </connectionFactory>
```

and the java code looks like this:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class TopicProducer {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TopicProducer.class);

  public TopicProducer() throws Exception {
    LOG.info("Starting TopicProducer");
  }

  @Resource(lookup = "java:app/KafkaConnectionFactory")
  KafkaConnectionFactory kafkaConnectionFactory;

  public void send(final String msg) {
    try (KafkaConnection connection = kafkaConnectionFactory.createConnection()) {

      LOG.info("Send message: {}", msg);

      connection.send(new ProducerRecord("demoTopic", msg));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }
}
```

But now I get a NullPointerException on the @Resource. My guess is that the resource adapter cannot be found.

Comment: Maybe try the Kafka connector instead of JMS - see this blog https://openliberty.io/blog/2019/09/13/microprofile-reactive-messaging.html

Comment: Its for a showcase. The Kafka Connector and Microprofile reactive messaging work, I am trying to use JMS for an example